# RSpec: Testing JS with Capybara: is it possible to run many "it" blocks after each other (without resetting the db, etc.)?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I want to make sure that some small JS is working as expected.

Because Capybara needs much more time when running examples with JS enabled, I tend to put all the needed assertions into one single spec, so they can become quite long and complex.

Here is a current example:

```
it 'provides "select all/none" buttons for the preferred regions (and updates the badge)', js: true do
  @user.profile = create :profile, preferred_regions_switzerland: [:zh, :ag, :sh],
                                   preferred_regions_germany: [],
                                   preferred_regions_austria: [:sbg]

  visit edit_user_profile_path

  # Make sure that the script is initialised for all countries
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Switzerland 3'
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Austria 1'

  # Click "Select all"
  click_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
  within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
    expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).to be_empty

    click_button 'Select all'

    expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').count).to eq Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size
  end
  expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany #{Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size}"

  # Click "Select none"
  within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
    click_button 'Select none'

    expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').count).to be 0
  end
  expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 0"

  # Manually select a checkbox
  within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
    check 'Bayern'
  end
  expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 1"

  # Manually deselect a checkbox
  within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
    uncheck 'Bayern'
  end
  expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 0"
end
```

Output:

```
- it provides "select all/none" buttons for the preferred regions (and updates the badge)
```

I wonder whether there is a way to split this example into many "it" blocks that are run sequentially, so the database wouldn't reset, and each would share the current context, etc.?

Some pseudo code:

```
sequential_examples js: true do
  it 'initialises the badges' do
    @user.profile = create :profile, preferred_regions_switzerland: [:zh, :ag, :sh],
                                     preferred_regions_germany: [],
                                     preferred_regions_austria: [:sbg]

    visit edit_user_profile_path

    # Make sure that the script is initialised for all countries
    expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Switzerland 3'
    expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
    expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Austria 1'
  end

  it 'provides "select all/none" buttons for the preferred regions' do
    # Click "Select all"
    click_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
    within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
      expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).to be_empty

      click_button 'Select all'

      expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').count).to eq Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size
    end
    expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany #{Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size}"

    # Click "Select none"
    within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
      click_button 'Select none'

      expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').count).to be 0
    end
    expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 0"
  end

  it 'updates the badge' do
    # Manually select a checkbox
    within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
      check 'Bayern'
    end
    expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 1"

    # Manually deselect a checkbox
    within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
      uncheck 'Bayern'
    end
    expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany 0"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
- it initialises the badges
- it provides "select all/none" buttons for the preferred regions
- it updates the badge
```

This would result in a much nicer output but would still be very fast.

I know that this goes "against" some very important testing principles, but wisely used, it could tear very long examples apart and provide nicer output and even maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the exact thing you're asking by giving the examples (`it` blocks) that you don't want to reset the database some tag and changing `DatabaseCleaner.strategy` in an `around` hook that is constrained to that tag. ([The RSpec documentation shows how to constrain a hook to a tag.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters))

That approach has issues, however:

- It would be easy to mistakenly use the tag on an example that did need the database to be reset (for example by deleting an example that did reset the database before an example that did not).
- You would not be isolating your examples from one another, so one example could leave behind state that could make the next example invalid.

All this trouble comes from using a very heavy tool to test all of the small details of your code. Consider a different approach: use the Javascript driver in only a small number of feature specs (where each feature spec tests a user-visible feature end-to-end), and use a Javascript unit testing framework like Jasmine to test the details of your Javascript like you're testing above. You would write a separate, isolated unit test for each of the interactions above, and maybe more to test sequences of selecting and/or deselecting. You would then have appropriately isolated tests, less big slow tests, and more small fast ones.

Side note: You could make your long examples easier to read by extracting a method for each action/assertion pair:

```
it 'provides "select all/none" buttons for the preferred regions (and updates the badge)', js: true do
  @user.profile = create :profile, preferred_regions_switzerland: [:zh, :ag, :sh],
                                   preferred_regions_germany: [],
                                   preferred_regions_austria: [:sbg]    
  visit edit_user_profile_path
  script_is_initialized_for_all_countries
  selecting_all_in_a_country_selects_all_regions_in_that_country
  # etc.
end

def script_is_initialized_for_all_countries
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Switzerland 3'
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
  expect(page).to have_link 'Preferred regions in Austria 1'
end

def selecting_all_in_a_country_selects_all_regions_in_that_country
  click_link 'Preferred regions in Germany 0'
  within '#preferred_regions_germany' do
    expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).to be_empty # wouldn't be necessary in an isolated test!
    click_button 'Select all'
    expect(all('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').count).to eq Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size
  end
  expect(page).to have_link "Preferred regions in Germany #{Profile.preferred_regions_germany.options.size}"
end

# etc.
```

But that wouldn't isolate the tests, so I would still do what I said above.

Comment: These are interesting informations, thank you. Jasmine etc. are truly useful libraries.